# Unable to execute bash script in windows cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

I am trying to execute bash script on windows using cygwin but getting error as commands not found

sample : test.sh

`#!/bin/bash
ls`

and I am executing it as 
`C:\Apps\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe /cygdrive/g/Scripts/test.sh`

getting error as 
test.sh: line 2: ls: command not found

Comment: `/usr/bin/bash test.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running this from the Windows command prompt, or from a Windows batch file, in order for your PATH and other environment variables to be set correctly, you need to invoke the `--login` option.  Run your command as follows:

```
 C:\Apps\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -c "/cygdrive/g/Scripts/test.sh"
```

This should do the trick.